# How do I set a range of views results?

Tags: views

I have 2 views in a page. The first view displays 3 articles and the second view displays a list of all the articles. The problem is that I get duplicated articles in the second view since it is displaying all the articles.

I need to set a range of the last 3 articles added to Drupal and display them on the first view  and on the second view I need to display the remaining articles. I´ve been looking for something like this is in the filters but I haven´t found something.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding an offset (you can find this in the pager options in your view), in your example "3". The offset "3" will show all results, but skips the first 3. Make sure that the sort criterea in both views are the same.

[image]

Comment: glad I could help :)